# Import bootstrap on sapper template

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

i'm having some trouble. I installed from node-modules jquery and bootstrap, I copied the files:

- bootstrap.min.css, jquery.min.js, bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.bundle.min.js

On static/lib
Then in template.html i put

```
<script rel="stylesheet" src="../static/lib/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="../static/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/lib/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

The console tell me that the files are not found (error 404).

Answer (score 0):

The `static` folder shouldn't be part of the URL. Have you tried this?

```html
<script rel="stylesheet" src="/lib/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, now it seems that it works, but i have this error on bootstrap.min.css Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' sapper-dev-client.js:21, why? I tried copy/paste from cdn but it has the same error